# Facebook PHP SDK V4: two login buttons

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, sdk

I would like to have two login buttons on my page. I'm not too familier with the coding of the SDK, is this possible?

One button works fine, but the second button doesn't. It just changes the url to index.php?code=wKdOAOLK... without logging in.

Any workaround?

code:

```
// added in v4.0.0
require './facebook-sdk/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\GraphUser;

// start session

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'x','x' );

// login helper with redirect_uri

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost/' );

try {
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
// When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
// When validation fails or other local issues
}



// see if we have a session 
if ( isset( $session ) ) {   
...
}
```

Buttons, both the same code:

```
<?php echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '"><img src="facebook.png"></a>'; ?>

<?php echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '"><img src="facebook.png"></a>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook uses a `state` parameter in its login process, to prevent CSRF attacks. That parameters is a random value that gets stored into the session, and is checked for a match in the next step.

Now, the `getLoginUrl` method generates a *new* random value for `state` each time it is called. So by calling this method twice, you are generating *two different* random `state` values, and therefor the second one overwrites the first one stored into the session, so in the end only one of them will match, and the other one won’t and will therefor cause an error.

So, don’t call `getLoginUrl` twice – instead, call it once, store the returned URL, and only *output* it two times.

```
$facebookLoginURL = $helper->getLoginUrl();

<?php echo '<a href="' . $facebookLoginURL . '"><img src="facebook.png"></a>'; ?>

<?php echo '<a href="' . $facebookLoginURL . '"><img src="facebook.png"></a>'; ?>
```